# How to convert an Enum which is a generic parameter to another Enum?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, enums, type-conversion

I have some enum

```
enum BasicEnum
{
    BasicValue1,
    BasicValue2
    //...
}
```

What I would like to have is something similar to

```
public void Foo<TEnum>(TEnum someEnum)
    where TEnum : struct, IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible
{
    switch (someEnum)
    {
        case BasicEnum.BasicValue1:
            //...
            break;
        case BasicEnum.BasicValue2:
            //...
            break;
    }
}
```

All the `TEnum` types contain only the values that present in `BasicEnum`.

Of course such code is not being compiled so I tried to change it onto this:

```
public void Foo<TEnum>(TEnum someEnum)
    where TEnum : struct, IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible
{
    BasicEnum basicEnum = (BasicEnum)someEnum;

    switch (basicEnum)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

As expected here I have an error again *'Cannot convert type 'TEnum' to 'BasicEnum''*

It's not so difficult to find a trick like

```
var value = Convert.ToInt32(someEnum);
var basicValue = (BasicEnum)value;
```

But this solution doesn't seem the one I like so much. Is there a better way?

Comment: no i don't think there is a better way. A cast cannot be avoided. At best you can consider using `TryParse`. `Enum.TryParse<BasicEnum>(someEnum.ToString(), out basicValue );`

Comment: It seems better than `Convert.ToInt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
( BasicEnum )Enum.ToObject( typeof( BasicEnum ), someEnum )
```

Answer (score 2):

Given the Following Enums

```
public enum FirstEnum
{
    FirstEnum1,
    FirstEnum2,
    FirstEnum3
}

public enum SecondEnum
{
    SecondEnum1,
    SecondEnum2,
    SecondEnum3
}
```

You can cast the second enum to a first enum by doing the following.

```
SecondEnum secEnum = SecondEnum.SecondEnum2;

FirstEnum firstEnum = (FirstEnum)Enum.ToObject(typeof(FirstEnum), secEnum);
```

`firstEnum` will now equal `FirstEnum2`

You can also create a generic method to convert your enums to your BasicType (i.e. FirstEnum)

```
public FirstEnum ConvertToFirstEnum(object enumToConvert)
{
    FirstEnum value = (FirstEnum)Enum.ToObject(typeof(FirstEnum), enumToConvert);
    return value;
}
```

And Call the function as followed:

```
FirstEnum firstEnum = ConvertToFirstEnum(SecondEnum.SecondEnum3);
```

The Value of `firstEnum` will equal `FirstEnum3`

Answer (score 0):

It is not the prettiest one but you can use (with proper cast checks added):

```
BasicEnum basicEnum = (BasicEnum)(object)someEnum;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with `var success = BasicEnum.TryParse(someEnum.ToString(), out basicEnum)`, if I understood what you need.

Comment: try parse is a static method on the Enum class. It cannot be available for BasicEnum